libvirtdbus change home folder
Is there a process to change home folder for libvirtdbus  account?
I am using KVM to run VMs on RHEL 8. Also using cockpit.
# /etc/shadow
libvirtdbus:x:979:978:Libvirt D-Bus bridge:/:/sbin/nologin
#

google search returned no results.
